# Sort by start time, breaking ties on end time

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a list of objects with start and end times:

```
let times = [
    {start: moment().add(1, 'days'), end: moment().add(2, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(1, 'days'), end: moment().add(2, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(4, 'days'), end: moment().add(5, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(1, 'days'), end: moment().add(7, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(2, 'days'), end: moment().add(3, 'days')},
]
```

I'd like to sort these times by start time (earliest to latest) while breaking ties with end time (shorter end time comes first).

So the results would look like this:

```
let sortedTimes = [
    {start: moment().add(1, 'days'), end: moment().add(2, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(1, 'days'), end: moment().add(2, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(1, 'days'), end: moment().add(7, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(2, 'days'), end: moment().add(3, 'days')},
    {start: moment().add(4, 'days'), end: moment().add(5, 'days')},
]
```

Is there a preferred Javascript way to do this with higher order functions/ minimal syntax? I began writing a script but the logic contains a lot of `if - else if - else` syntax, was wondering if there was a better way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, I'm assuming you're using moment.js. This doesn't utilize a higher order function, but just uses the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method with a custom comparator function and the syntax is pretty terse:

```
times.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.start.isBefore(b.start) ? -1 : a.start.isSame(b.start) ? a.end.isBefore(b.end) ? -1 : 1 : 1;
});
```

Written out:

```
times.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.start.isBefore(b.start)) {
        return -1; // a before b
    } else if (a.start.isSame(b.start)) {
        // break tie on end
        if (a.end.isBefore(b.end)) {
            return -1; // a before b
        } else {
            return 1; // b before a
        }
    } else {
        return 1; // b before a
    }
}
```

Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zOSXwZwJV6sn0IC3R9ij?p=preview) if you want to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps lodash `sortBy`:

```
_.sortBy(times, ['start', 'end']);
```

See:

- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/dist/lodash.core.js#L2130-L2139